# Hide labels of empty elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup, which is repeated 14 times on my page. Each section is a little different, but includes a internal/external label, which has a class="sectionLabel". If the div that is immediately under the section label is empty, I need to hide the section label. Below is what I have tried that does not work...it hides all section labels. How can I hide only the section labels where the corresponding div does not have any children?

```
<div class="column1">
    <span id="internalOutputsLabel1" class="sectionLabel">Internal Outputs</span>
    <div id="internalOutputStrategicPlanningPhase1" class="linkHolder"> <!-- If empty, hide the label above -->
    </div>

    <span id="externalOutputsLabel1" class="sectionLabel">Extenal Outputs</span>
    <div id="externalOutputStrategicPlanningPhase1" class="linkHolder"> <!-- If empty, hide the label above -->
    </div>
</div>
```

What I've tried:

```
$(".linkHolder").each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).empty)
    {
        $(".sectionLabel").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just filter it like this

```
$('.sectionLabel').filter(function() {
    return $(this).next('.linkHolder').is(':empty')
}).hide();
```

Note that jQuery's `$(element).empty()` does something else, it empties the element, removing all it's content.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not work. I've created a fiddle so you could see and maybe see why. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ee6gyex/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You almost made it:

```
$(".linkHolder").each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).html() == '')
    {
        $(this).prev().hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it does not work. I've created a fiddle so you could see and maybe see why [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ee6gyex/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('div:empty').remove(); });
```